# How to change existing COLUMN type to SERIAL in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sequence, ddl, postgresql-12

The following statement doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN column_id set default nextval('my_table_column_id_seq');
```

So how to change id column to auto increment?

Error:

```
null value in column \"column_id"\ violates non null constraint.
```

This happens when I insert without column_id. I need it to be auto increment.
Postgres Version is 12.

My insert:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column2, column3)
VALUES ('rndmstring', 5);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a valid Postgres error message

Comment: Added error message and description of how it was produced.

Comment: That statement won't result in that error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yet it produces that error when im trying to insert without id.

Comment: Then show us the code that does the INSERT and causes that error, not something unrelated. The `alter table`  will **not** cause that error

Comment: Added insert statement.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8036ec1fd00ca7977fef7b868ad4635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. I had the id set as parameter in my endpoint for creating a new table.

So instead of this nodejs endpoint:

```
exports.createMy_table = async (column_id, column2, column3) => {
  try {
    const result = await client.query(
      "INSERT INTO my_table (column_id, column2, column3) VALUES ($1, $2, $3
      [column_id, column2, column3]
    );
    return result.rows;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

I create without id.

```
 exports.createMy_table = async (column2, column3) => {
      try {
        const result = await client.query(
          "INSERT INTO my_table (column2, column3) VALUES ($1, $2,
          [column2, column3]
        );
        return result.rows;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the sequence starting with the max value +1 of existing values for column_id :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_column_id_seq START WITH <MAX VALUE OF column_id+1>;
```

after checking out if this query

```
SELECT 1
  FROM my_table
 HAVING COUNT(distinct column_id)=COUNT(column_id)
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN column_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)=
        SUM(CASE WHEN column_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 1 END);
```

returns 1 for non-null and uniqueness of the concerned column's values, and then use your existing command

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN column_id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_column_id_seq');
```

command and make sure all the existing values for column_id is unique, then issue :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(column_id);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc531c56ad4402329569cae182675c08)</kbd>

Comment: No. Insert statement wont go trough without entering is aswell.